# How do I assign a material to an Archipack object?

Tags: materials, add-on, archipack-add-on

I use Blender 2.79 and am still pretty much a beginner.

I tried both Archipack and Archimesh. Archipack seems a bit more comfortable but I don't know how to assign a Material to it or change it from the default grey to something different. In Archimesh that is easy. I would like to use the Principle BSDF Shader and Cycles.

I cannot find documentation on either of those addons either... just a long thread in a forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

- Pull the arrow located at the upper right corner to the left.
- Go to the "editor type" beside (left side) the "view" toolbar located at the bottom.
- Select the node editor.
- Make sure you are on Cycles render mode.
- Select the Archipack object and go to the materials tab.
- Click on use nodes.

[image]

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to bring up the context menu then hover to Shader> Principled BSDF

Comment: Well that is what I did and what you normally do to assign a material. It does not work for my archipack wall though. It does not change. If I add a cube and do the same thing it works.

Comment: I could assign materials only in edit mode, not in object mode ... is that normal?

Comment: Each side of the wall is assigned an independent material (check the materials tab). Wall2_alt1, Wall2_cuts, etc. If you want all of them under the same material then click the minus (-) sign and leave only one or delete all of them (-) and create a new one (+) plus sign.

Answer (score 2):

Archipack can take advantage of a predefined material library.
If the default material library is missing, you get dumb white materials assigned.
Please take a look at https://github.com/s-leger/archipack/wiki/Materials in order to setup your default material library.
The aswer of @light-pankakes remains still valid when it comes to setup new materials.